# Send email with a resized picture with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, jpeg, bmp, aspx-user-control

It seems I need to get "g" into the attachment in place of fileUpload1.PostedFile.  I just can't seem to figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.  I tried to use g.save(@"c:\Temp\test.jpg"), but it won't save either :(

```
var  bmp = new Bitmap(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
                 var newImage = new Bitmap(200,200);
                 var g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
                  g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, 200, 200);

                string fileName = 
Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                Attachment myAttachment = new 
Attachment(FileUpload1.FileContent, fileName);
                mail.Attachments.Add(myAttachment);
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `g` anyway? I can't figure it out from your code - what is it *supposed* to do? Is there something missing in this example?

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.  g is a resized bitmap.  I believe it exists only in memory.  I need to get it out from memory and send it as an email attachment.  If I have to save it first I am ok

Comment: Ah, I see. What's the exception you get what you use `g.Save` and why do you use `Path.GetFileName` on a FileName?

Comment: By the way, you don't need to (and shouldn't) save it into a file. You can just use a MemoryStream. (Just remember to "reset" it by seeking to byte 0 before you use it for the attachment).

Comment: I did some research and it seems I cant use "save" on a graphics file only on a bmp.  The Path.GetFileName is just for naming the file.  I am pretty new, I am not sure how to use a "MemoryStream"   I will keep googling at least you gave me something to search for :)

Comment: *"I cant use "save" on a graphics file only on a bmp"* Doesn't really make sense to me, I think you should take a look at the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx. As for the MemoryStream: That's a very helpful class when it comes to saving data to memory instead of files. I highly recommend you familiarize yourself with it, you might need it again. Good luck

Comment: well I am still a lost puppy, but thank you for Trying to assist :)